# Default Member - SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

Trying to figure out what the default member adds to this scipt

```
([DateTool].[Aggregation].[Previous Month]) =
iif( 
([DateTool].[Aggregation].DefaultMember, ParallelPeriod(dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].[RPT Period Month],1,[dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].currentmember)) = null,        
NULL, 
([DateTool].[Aggregation].DefaultMember,ParallelPeriod([dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].[RPT Period Month],1,[dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].currentmember))
);
```

This is from a utility dimension. Calculation script.
I get the IIF, and I get the ParallelPeriod.
But what effect does "(DefaultMember, ParallelPeriod)" have?

Comment: Please add the definition of default member, maybe this will help somehow. But I put my supposition below w/o it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it used to avoid infinite recursion. This technique is used in this kind of dynamic calculations.

Let's say we run some MDX script with `WHERE [DateTool].[Aggregation].[Previous Month]`.

Server takes this calculation from your formula (without `[DateTool].[Aggregation].DefaultMember`), it uses `ParallelPeriod` as usual, but than it needs `[DateTool].[Aggregation].[Previous Month]` as a part of tuple with other dimensions (our `WHERE` filter), so it takes from this formula again and again...

So we always need to have some fixed member to avoid infinite recursion.

That is my understanding, please correct if it's somewhere or totally wrong.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti, sorry for the off-topic question: could you please tell me, how to highlight some parts of answer (as you did to improve visualization of my text) or give a link to some related topic?

Comment: Yo get everything [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I suspected, you hadn't hovered over my previous comment. The `here` is a hyperlink to the URL I just mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the calculated member is built to have values **only** *when the slicer has any member from `[dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].[RPT Period Month]` level*. This is my opinion imitates the **`ISCROSSFILTERED`**  functionality of `DAX`.

The member is built such that `[DateTool].[Aggregation].[Previous Month]` would hold value only when
the slicer has a member from `[dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].[RPT Period Month]`

`[DateTool].[Aggregation].DefaultMember` is as good as `[DateTool].[Aggregation].[ALL]`
It is as good as leaving out `[DateTool].[Aggregation]` hierarchy from the query

If slicer does not have a member from `[dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].[RPT Period Month]`, 
then `[dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].currentmember` is as good as `[dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].[ALL]`
The previous member in this case(which is returned by `ParallelPeriod` function) is undefined and hence, `NULL` would be returned.

If slicer has the member, a `non null` member would be returned.

To further illustrate upon this:
(Please read through the comments)

```
([DateTool].[Aggregation].[Previous Month]) =
iif( 
(
[DateTool].[Aggregation].[ALL], 
ParallelPeriod([dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].[RPT Period Month],1,[dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].currentmember)
) //If a member from dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].[RPT Period Month] level is not in slicer then it would evaluate to NULL
= null,        
NULL, //In that case the previous month should evaluate to NULL
//Otherwise, it should give the "previous month"
([DateTool].[Aggregation].[ALL],
ParallelPeriod([dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].[RPT Period Month],1,[dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].currentmember))
);
```